# Pass values taken from an HTML form into a TaffyDB database, located in a seperate .js script

Tags: javascript, html, database, taffydb, taffy

I am trying to take radio and checkbox values from an HTML form, and save/export/pass the values to an external javascript file where the TaffyDB structured database is initialized.

HTML:

```
            <strong> <font color="black">Color</strong></font>
            <form name="colorForm">
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Red">
                <font color="black">Red
                    <br>
                </font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Orange">
                <font color="black">Orange
                    <br>
                </font>
                <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Yellow">
                <font color="black">Yellow
                    <br>

                <!--function to return checkbox values for colors-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function get_color() {
                        //console.log(document.colorForm);
                        for (var i = 0; i < document.colorForm.length; i++) {
                            while (document.colorForm[i].checked && i < document.colorForm.length) {
                                var check_color = document.colorForm[i].value;
                                return check_color;
                                colorList.insert({color:get_color});
                            }//end of while
                        }//end of for
                    }//end of get_color
                </script>
```

JavaScript:

var colorList = TAFFY();

Comment: Java Script is a client side scripting language , you may want to import the js file to the posted html rather

Comment: I have imported the .js file in my header <script src="taffydb-master/colorbase.js"></script> but when I run a console.log(alert(colorList())) , I am getting an undefined message, and any of the values that I think are being passed inserted into the DB are not appearing

Comment: how are you calling the function get_color(), Which event

Comment: in the while loop, for every color value that is checked, I would like to insert the results of the get_color function, colorList.insert({color:get_color});

Comment: "[] 
There are no child objects"   is what is returned by entering console.log(colorList().get())

Answer (score 0):

you are returning check_color before you insert in your db.

The return statement **ends a function**, you cannot execute code after it.

try placing your return statement elsewhere.